# How do, or can you hide account contacts on the Galaxy S III?

Tags: contacts, sync, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Okay, so I just upgraded from the Galaxy S Captivate to a shiny new Galaxy S III.

In both the stock TouchWiz ROM and the AOKP ROM I later ran, on my Captivate, i could set specific accounts to not show their contacts in my address book. Specifically, while I want to sync my Facebook contacts to get photos for people, I don't want all my Facebook contacts showing up in my phone address book.

Poke around as I might though, I cannot find any way to hide a specific account from the address book on the Galaxy S III. Is there any way to do this?

I should note, I am running the AT&T version.

Comment: Generally that stuff is under `Settings | Accounts & Sync`.

Comment: Well, the accounts are all listed there, but there's nothing about showing/hiding them in the address book. On my stock Captivate there was a setting directly in Samsung's contacts/address book app. But I see no such settings in their new on on the S III.

Comment: Hmm, backed it up and tried flashing in the stock ICS contacts app, and it would't run.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just encountered this same problem on a new Galaxy SIII with Verizon. I'm using stock Android 4.1.2 and found the answer to be simple. Just open the Contacts app, then click the phone's Menu button, then choose the "Contacts to Display" menu, the select the gear icon to the right of "Customized list", then choose the respective contacts account, then uncheck (or check) the email contact groups that you wish to hide, press "Done" in the upper right when finished. That should have activate the "Customized list", but you can return to that menu to confirm.

That's it! simple and no need to install custom ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, That particular option was in CYM7.5 on my Dell streak. was a nice addition IMO.

Only thing I can suggest, unless there's some sort of third party app for it, is to install a custom rom such as CYM or any other AOSP ROM, I doubt any of the Customized samsung rom's will give you this.

You will lose all the official Samsung junk with an AOSP rom, but at least it'll be stock ICS rather than the crappy samsung replacement apps.

(I like some of the samsung mods such as palm swipe to screen grab, but the SMS app and Contacts app suck)

Comment: Annoying thing is even Samsung had this in their old TouchWIZ, but took it out!  :-?  The built in Camera app is pretty nice too... that's really the biggest thing keeping me from jumping to an AOSP ROM; though I might once AOKP gets their JB ROM out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to contacts and open context menu. You can hide contacts without phone number in settings or you can select which account to show.